# Adding a CardView to a FrameLayout ignores LayoutParams defined in the CardView's XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, view

In my MainActivity I'm using a FloatingActionButton to add CardViews to an existing container (a FrameLayout) programatically.

But when I add the CardView all LayoutParams (e.g. width, height, margin, etc) are ignored. Is there a way to use the params specified in the XML File?

Here is my code:

card_view.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardViewBackground">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="example Text" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
            android:text="@string/default_main_activity_msg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="16dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_add"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:onClick="addCard"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.life_hacks.liftnotes.activity.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and finally the code I use to add the CardView:

```
public void addCard(View v){
    View cardView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.card_view, null);
    FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_body);
    if(container != null){
        container.addView(card_view);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass a root `ViewGroup` - i.e., your `container` - as the last argument in the `inflate()` call for the params to be applied. Also, are you sure you want to use a `FrameLayout` for that?

Comment: @MikeM.  I'll give it a try, and no I'm not sure ... lol, I'm fairly new to android development and this is my first try to make an app. What View would you recommend?

Comment: I would guess that you want a vertically-oriented `LinearLayout`. Oh, also, you won't need to call `addView()` if you pass the `container` `ViewGroup`. It'll be added automatically.

Comment: @MikeM. ah perfekt... even solved another problem I had. now i can add it multiple times! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I had edited my comment. You don't want to call `addView()` when you pass the `ViewGroup` to `inflate()`. And make sure you've changed the XML element, `container`'s type, and the cast on `findViewById()`.

Comment: @MikeM. yup saw it a little too late, the `addView()` call caused the problem. if you want to create an answer I'll happily accept it

Comment: Sure thing. Gimme a minute. I'm on a phone, atm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `layout_*` attributes of an XML-defined `View` to be applied correctly, the `ViewGroup` that will hold it must be supplied to the `LayoutInflater`. In this case, it means that you need to pass your `container` as the last argument in the `View.inflate()` call. Doing this will also cause the inflated `View` to be automatically added to the `ViewGroup`, so you must not call `addView()` with it, or you'll get an `IllegalStateException`.

Also, since you'll be adding multiple `View`s to your `container`, it would seem that a `LinearLayout` would be more appropriate than a `FrameLayout`. I would also mention that if you plan on adding a lot of additional `View`s, a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView` might end up being a better option.